# amsplain style: change punctuation before note?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, amsplain

In the Bibliography list produced by BibTeX with the `amsplain` style, can the punctuation before the note field be changed from a comma to a semicolon?

For example,

> Paul Bernays, *Axiomatic set theory,* 2 ed., Dover, 1991;
>   republication of 2 ed., North-Holland, 1958.

instead of:

> Paul Bernays, *Axiomatic set theory,* 2 ed., Dover, 1991,
>   republication of 2 ed., North-Holland, 1958.

Comment: `amsplain.bst` uses the same function (which adds “comma and space”) for separating the various fields, so you're out of luck. See lines 237 and 238.

Comment: I was afraid of that! I guess I can "cheat" by hand-editing the `.bbl` file before the final latex run.

Comment: Doing the change in the `.bst` would require very extensive work, as far as I can see.